# Перевод из десятичной системы счисления к двоичную c++

Tags: c++

Как убрать лишние нули?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
int main()
{
    int x, dec;
    cout << "Enter: "; cin >> dec;
    for (int i = 31; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        cout << ((dec >> i) & 1);
        if (i % 4 == 0 && i) cout << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Просто не выводите их пока не встретите первую единицу

Comment: Это не вариант, так как если ты вводишь (к примеру " 3 ", то программа должна вывести "0011"), а с вашим предложением она выведет только "11".

Comment: Идите по [нибблам](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B1%D0%BB). Пропустите все нулевые, а потом печатайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main() {
  int x, dec;
  bool flag = false;
  cout << "Enter: ";
  cin >> dec;
  for (int i = 31; i >= 0; --i) {
    bool symb = ((dec >> i) & 1);
    if (symb && !flag) {
      flag = true;
      int k = 3 - i % 4;
      for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
        cout << 0;
      }
    }

    if (flag) {
      cout << symb;
      if (i % 4 == 0 && i)
        cout << " ";
    }
  }
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал все через bitset

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <algorithm>


int main() {

    std::bitset<64> b(836);

    auto s = b.to_string();
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    auto p = s.find("1");

    s = s.substr(p);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```